# Windows 10: Everything in English except for Keyboard (German)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, language

I'm Austrian - therefore I want my keyboard to be in German, all the time so I can write ü,ö,ä, etc. and not having z and y change places (QWERTZ-keyboard).

But I want all apps, and everything on my laptop to be in English. Until now everything worked well but about a week ago something changed. Maybe I'm pressing some keyboard shortcut all the time but the keyboard layout constantly changes to english. I tried changing it in the settings

"Settings >> Time & Language >> Region & Language >> Advanced Keyboard Settings >> Language Bar Options >> Advanced Key Settings >> Setting everything to None"

But that didn't work. Does anyone know how I can change my language to English on my Windows 10 Notebook but keep the keyboard layout for German all the time and disabling ALL keyboard-shortcuts which would change that keyboard layout again.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just remove the US keyboard (and keep the only the layout you're actually using).

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia where can I remove keyboards? I can only remove languages, which I don't want to.

Comment: Click the first Language listed - this is your system language - then Options and you'll see the keyboards.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia mHm, that didn't work very well. I could change the keyboard language but still I have somewhere an UK keyboard, although my languge is the irish english?

Comment: How many languages are listed? Perhaps the UK keyboard is under other languages (with multiple keyboards you can toggle them whether or not they "belong" to the main language). In this case check all languages and remove the keyboard layouts you aren't using. In same you'll have to add one before removing. Let's suppose your system is Irish but you also have UK English installed. This automatically installs the default UK EN keyboard layout.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I added a screenshot of how it looks

Comment: The screenshots show everything is as I suggested. So, you're saying it changes to anther layout even if not present in settings? If that's the case I can only suggest rebooting after confirming the settings. If you notice the same behavior then maybe something else is wrong with yor Windows, it definitely shouldn't be toggling to a keyboard that isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I test in my Windows 10 environment.

**Way 1:**

According to your screenshot, you may add German keyboard in **Settings->Region & language-> Languages->English (United States)->Options**:

[image]

Then we get the German keyboard as below, it is an **English(United States)-based German keyboard**:

[image]

**Way 2:**

I think we can try to add German keyboard in **Settings->Region & language-> Languages->Add a language**.

Then we get the German keyboard as below, it is an **German(Austria)-based German keyboard**:

[image]

I think keyboard-shortcuts in **way 2** does not affect the keyboard layout, so we do not disable keyboard-shortcuts, we can  also use switch the input method with the mouse. And keyboard-shortcuts in **way 2** may affect the keyboard layout, because it is an **English(United States)-based German keyboard**.

We can try **Way 2**, hope it helps.